# Rake "already initialized constant WFKV_" warning

Tags: ruby, rake

Trying to run `rake cucumber:ok` and am getting this error:

`/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_`

Then:
`Command failed with status (1): [/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin...]`

I am pretty new to Rails and Google didn't turn anything up for this error.

**EDIT:** I've tried adding `bundle exec` and that makes no difference.

Here's what I got with `--trace`:

```
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `sh'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:104:in `run'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.1.0/lib/cucumber/rake/task.rb:193:in `block in define_task'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/dev/.rbenv/versions/1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => cucumber:ok
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I started having the same problem this evening. It seems to be related to Rack 1.3.4. I fixed it by adding this to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack', '1.3.3'
```

Then running:

```
bundle update rack
```

Incidentally, I tried Bozhidar's suggestion before this, but to no avail.

Comment: From the comments in common_192.rb ("Stolen from ruby core's uri/common.rb @32618ba to fix DoS issues in 1.9.2" and "This should probably be removed once there is a Ruby 1.9.2 patch level that includes this fix.") it looks as if this was added to rack to prevent a denial-of-service attack. It purposely monkeypatches a vulnerability in Ruby but the monkeypatch results in the "already initialized constant" warning. So it looks like the choice is either to revert to 1.3.3 as suggested by Daniel or to get the fix and put up with the warning for awhile.

Comment: In my case, the warning was preventing asset pipeline precompilation, so reverting to 1.3.3 was the only option.

Comment: A fix for this has been added - https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/235f83cb88650beaa7fd0089ee0d19ca46507fc0 - so it should be in the next release of rack. If you really need rack 1.3.4 for some reason you could do something like `require 'uri/common'; ::URI.send :remove_const, :WFKV_` before you require rack. It'll even work in your Gemfile.

Comment: Just a minor note:  I would not do bundle update but instead `bundle update rack`.  `bundle update` will want to update all gems.

Answer (score 8):

Rack 1.3.5 is out now, which has fixed this warning.

Answer (score 0):

you should uninstall rake-0.9.2
and install rack 1.6.13

```
gem uninstall rake
gem install  rack 1.6.13
```

Answer (score -1):

So, I included:

require 'uri/common'; ::URI.send :remove_const, :WFKV_

however the comment which says "it **will work** in the Gemfile" in fact should read "**Must be** in the Gemfile."