# rvm rack ruby error already initialized constant WFKV_

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rack

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rake “already initialized constant WFKV_” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624661/rake-already-initialized-constant-wfkv-warning)

I'm getting this error in my terminal when I use any `ruby, rake or rails` related commands.
Commands are being executed and work fine, but before that I receive his error. Any suggestions? Thanks for advise!

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
```

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Best answer is a link to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

I put `gem 'rake', '1.3.3'` in my Gemfile and ran `bundle update rake` and it works now.