# rack and cucumber; not sure how to resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I am having the same issue mentioned here: [Rake "already initialized constant WFKV_" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624661/rake-already-initialized-constant-warning)

I changed my Gemfile to:

```
gem 'rack', '1.3.3'
```

If I run:`rake cucumber:ok --trace`
it looks like it runs:

`/Users/jt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default`

with the following errors:

```
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/jt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/...]
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh' 
/Users/jt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:36:in `sh'
```

If I run:

```
Sat Oct 08$ bundle exec cucumber
```

things seem to run ok.

How do I fix my gems so that `rake cucumber:ok` works ok?

thx

**edit #1**
Is there any way I could confirm which version of Rack that Cucumber is using? Or ensure that Rack 1.3.3 is **ALWAYS** being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try creating a temporary gemset and install bundle over there and try it out, following are the step to follow,

1. rvm gemset create temp_gemset
2. rvm gemset use temp_gemset
3. bundle install

Here temp_gemset is the name given to gemset

Comment: would this be to test the Rack version. Not so familiar with how these piece fit together in terms of this error. thx

Comment: Yes, if the issue is happening because of the rack version conflict, this should solve the issue. This is pretty simple, rvm generally installs all the required gems into a global directory. With the above steps, it will create a separate directory and install the specified gems(from gemset file) into that directory.

Ref: http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the rake task via bundle exec?

```
bundle exec rake cucumber:ok
```