# Rails 3.1 application server start error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I  have this old rails application which was working fine until recently. But now when I try to start rails server using

```
rails s
```

then it give error as -

```
  /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53: warning: already initialized constant WFKV_
  /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require': no such file to load -- false (LoadError)
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `require'
    from /home/rtdp/myapplication/config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `require'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:52:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
    from /home/rtdp/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@mygemset/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

what might be causing this, I am using 
ruby - 1.9.2p290
rails - 3.1.1
bundler - 1.0.18

**UPDATE:**

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624661/rake-already-initialized-constant-warning). Using the rack version 1.3.3 fixed the warning of WFKV constant.

Comment: Looks like you are using RVM. If you make a brand new gemset and run `bundle install` does it still give you that error?

Comment: i was using system ruby 1.9.2 before, tried installing new rvm 1.9.2 ruby and created new gemset for this, still the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, finally I found that the way I use including turn gem was the issue.

I was doing this -

```
 gem 'turn', :require => 'false'
```

My bad. Corrected this thing and it works now.